# Separate class TabPages - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a beginner in C# and Windows Forms, and I am trying to make a little application to manage different databases.
To do so, I would like to have a TabController with different TabPages, one for each database.
I already have a template of what will be inside of the TabPages, and I want to replicate it for every TabPage. So I would like to have a C# class for every TabPage so I can just copy/paste the template and change the data source.

The problem is Forms keeps creating Partial classes when I try to create a new form, or won't let me create a class binded to my TabPage.

Is there any way to have a TabPage have its own code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UserControl containing your database UI and a public "DataSource" property.   Then, place  one of the user controls on each tab page.